# Form validation with jquery.validate to show right and wrong icons by overriding errorplacement

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve the demo jquery validate plugin has [here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/). But what I want to solve is: if you click submit after page loads, the plugin shows validation msgs with cross symbol. And if you type something, the msg changes to checkmark image. But if you remove the text again, it shows the validation msg but with checkmark and not the cross image. I want to correct this for my website:

I am using jquery.validate for client-side validation. In order to show a right and cross icons with message of the validation, I am using icomoons icons set(the css approach). I have added my html and JS script below. I was trying to use the errorplacement to change the default container but doing this the icon from cross to right doesn't change if you input something in the textbox and then remove it again. The message appears but the icon doesn't change.

Also, I would like to learn any more efficient way to write jquery.validate to achieve the icon approach what I am doing here.

HTML section here:

```
 <!-- First step - form section starts here -->
         <form class="form-horizontal" id="sampleForm">
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="firstName">First Name:</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" placeholder="Peter">
                <div class="errormsgwrapper">
                 <span data-icon="&#xe000;" class="right hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                 <span data-icon="&#xe003;" class="wrong hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                 <div class="errormessage"></div>
                 </div> 
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label" for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
              <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Parker">
                <div class="errormsgwrapper">
                 <span data-icon="&#xe000;" class="right hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                 <span data-icon="&#xe003;" class="wrong hidden" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                 <div class="errormessage"></div>
                 </div> 
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
              <div class="controls pull-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Next &raquo;</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <hr>
        <!-- /form -->
```

Validation script:

```
$().ready(function() {

// validate signup form on keyup and submit

    $("#sampleForm").validate({

        rules: {
            firstName: "required",
            lastName: "required"
        },
        highlight: function(label) {
    $(label)
        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    $('label.error').removeClass('checked');
  },
  success: function(label) {
    label.parents(".errormsgwrapper").children('.wrong').addClass('hidden');
    label.parents(".errormsgwrapper").children('.right').removeClass('hidden');
    label.closest('.control-group').addClass('success');

  },
        messages: {
            firstName: {
                    required: "asdfds"
                },
            lastName: "Please enter your lastname"
        },
         errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            var errormsgwrapper = element.next(".errormsgwrapper");

                errormsgwrapper.children("span.right").addClass('hidden');
                errormsgwrapper.children("span.wrong").removeClass('hidden');
                error.appendTo(errormsgwrapper.children(".errormessage"));

         }

    });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution is here**
I have found the solution and also including a sample code below. We can use highlight/unhighlight to achieve that. I was trying in errorplacement, which doesn't fire when the class on the element changes from valid to error!! One can use classes or even html elements to show/hide using highlight and unhighlight as shown in js code below...

```
<div id="signupwrap">
        <form id="signupform" autocomplete="off" method="get" action="">
        <div class="question">
            <label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" />
        <div class="errormessagewrapper">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class=""></span>
        </div>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <div class="question">
            <label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
        <input type="text" name="lastname" />
        <div class="errormessagewrapper">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class=""></span>
        </div>
        </div>
         <br /><br />

            <input id="signupsubmit" name="signup" type="submit" value="Signup" />


          </table>
      </form>
  </div>
```

I have included that span tag so as to give proper styling to the icon or image whatever you want to show with the validation message.
JS code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// validate signup form on keyup and submit
var validator = $("#signupform").validate({

    rules: {
        firstname: "required",
        lastname: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        firstname: "Enter your firstname",
        lastname: "Enter your lastname"
    },

    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.appendTo(element.next('.errormessagewrapper').children());
    },
    // specifying a submitHandler prevents the default submit, good for the demo
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert("submitted!");
    },
    // set this class to error-labels to indicate valid fields
    success: function(label) {

    },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {


   $(element).next('.errormessagewrapper').children('span').addClass("icon-cancel").removeClass("icon-checkmark");

  },
  unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
     $(element).next('.errormessagewrapper').children('span').removeClass("icon-cancel").addClass("icon-checkmark");

  }
    });



});
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. When you fill in the form field correctly, the error should IMMEDIATELY disappear - not on blur.

Comment: my requirement was on blur, you can use the available events to handle your requirement.